# MATLAB Number looping

Tags: matlab, loops

I'm looping an array, multiple times with the order being changed every time the array restarts (using randperm).

My problem is that occasionally I get something like below for the order of my array:

```
1 3 5 6 8 7 2 4 9     
9 4 2 7 8 6 5 3 1
```

Notice that end of the first array loop is the same as the beginning of the next array loop. Is there any way to control this?

I have tried putting `rng (n)` and `randn(n)` just before the end of the loop, before it goes back to randomize the order and continue looping but that does not help.

EDIT - Code

```
for b = 1;
while b <= 2
  for n = randperm(length(V));
  disp(V {n});
  end
b = b+1;
end
end
```

Comment: You can check for this condition and re-randomize if it exists.

Comment: Can you please post the part of your code that contains the loop?

Comment: @MarkHughes Off-topic: the outside `for` loop seems redundant, as it performs only one iteration for `b=1` (so it can hardly be called a "loop")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a short solution that implements ja72's suggestion:

```
V = 1:9;
b = 1;
while b <= 10
  nextperm = randperm(length(V)); %// Generate a random permutation

  %// Verify permutation
  if (b > 1 && nextperm(1) == prevperm(end))
      continue
  end
  prevperm = nextperm;

  disp(V(nextperm));  
  b = b + 1;
end
```

Comment: +1 for using `randperm()` as well as for the few lines of code to achieve the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need, a check condition before settling on the random permutation?

```
matrix = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99];
randOrder = zeros(length(matrix));
randOrderIntermediate = zeros(length(matrix));
randOrderPrev = zeros(length(matrix));

for i = 1:10

%Store the previous random order
randOrderPrev = randOrder;
%Create interim random order
randOrderIntermediate = randperm(length(matrix));
%check condition, is the first the same as the previous end?
while randOrderIntermediate(end) == randOrderPrev(1)
    %whilst condition true, re-randomise
    randOrderIntermediate = randperm(length(matrix));
end
%since condition is no longer true, set the new random order to be the
%intermediate one
randOrder = randOrderIntermediate;

%As with your original code.
for n = randOrder
    disp(matrix(n))
end

end
```